# Read data from 2010's Access database from sql server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ms-access

I'm going to tell you my environment: Windows Server 2012 R2 64, ACCESS 2010 32, SQL SERVER 2008 R2 64 running with the Administrator account, AccessDatabaseEngine 32. I need connect the sql to 2010's bbdd access. I tried creating a linked server and using OPENDATASOURCE and OPENROWSET but allways I get the error

> The OLE DB provider 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' can not be used for
>   distributed queries because it is configured to run in simple
>   controlled threading mode.

I have been searching on internet and I followed all the stepsbut I still have the same error, I have also used SSMS with the Administrator and sa accounts and always the same error. As a curious and strange thing is that after installing the AccessDatabaseEngine 32 "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB" does not appear in the providers in Server Objects.

Thank you very much and greetings.

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', N'AllowInProcess', 1
EXEC master.dbo.sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', N'DynamicParameters', 1
exec sp_configure 'Advanced', 1
RECONFIGURE
GO
exec sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1
RECONFIGURE
GO
exec sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1
RECONFIGURE
GO
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
RECONFIGURE
GO
sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1
GO

EXEC sp_addlinkedserver   
   @server = N'DATOS',   
   @provider = N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',   
   @srvproduct = N'OLE DB Provider for ACE',  
   @datasrc = N'C:\SERVIDOR\DATOS\BBDDs.accdb';  
GO


SELECT id From OpenRowset('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',';Database=C:\SERVIDOR\DATOS\BBDDs.accdb;','SELECT * from Productos') as B
GO

SELECT *  FROM OPENDATASOURCE('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0','Data Source=C:\SERVIDOR\DATOS\BBDDs.accdb')...Productos
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the [64bit version of OLEDB driver](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255)

Comment: Thanks fededim. I already tried to do that, but it is not possible because on server 2012 is installed a 32 bit's access version and can't chage to 64 bits version because it's used for the maintenance of an access 2010 application that only executes in 32 bits.

Comment: Hmmm so you can't even install the 64bit driver if the 32bit driver is present ? I thought that both drivers could coexist, I fear that you do not see the driver in the providers of Sql server since it's 64bit.

Comment: Otherwise if this is not possible I fear that you have to install another machine with 32bit Sql Server just for accessing the access database and configure a linked server between the two instances.

Answer (score 0):

Enable the environemnt.

```
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;  
GO  
RECONFIGURE;  
GO  
EXEC sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1;  
GO  
RECONFIGURE;  
GO
```

Then, check to see if this works.

```
Insert Into database.schema.yourtable SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
'Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;Database=E:\Data\test.xls','SELECT * FROM [sheet1$]');
```